# jQuery docs says .submit() event does not bubble in IE. What does this mean?

Tags: jquery, events, submit, event-bubbling

From the [jQuery documentation for `.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/):

> The JavaScript submit event does not bubble in Internet Explorer. However, scripts that rely on event delegation with the submit event will work consistently across browsers as of jQuery 1.4, which has normalized the event's behavior.

What does this mean?

Comment: So what is your question? Are you asking how jQuery does it?

Comment: I'm wondering as far as the "event bubbling". From how I understand it, if I click on a link inside a div, the click will bubble down to the div as well. I am not sure how bubbling affects forms.

Comment: I don't think I can provide an adequate answer, but I will note that events don't bubble _down_, they bubble _up,_ where in your example the link is considered the bottom and the click event will, _after_ going to the link, bubble _up_ to the containing div, and then to that div's container, etc. Event "capturing" is the opposite of "bubbling" and goes _down_. See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it means is that jQuery has mimicked the submit event bubbling process to make it appear to bubble in browsers that do not natively support it. In essence, they are writing code to make it look like bubbling. The same goes for the `focus` and `blur` events. If you want to use those for delegation, use the normalized `focusin` and `focusout` events.